# Moving from web to native applications

Tags: mobile, hybrid

Got a problem, and I am pretty sure there is a solution for this.

Currently we have a Website that sells goods & integrates with a thirty party for shopping cart. The shopping cart integration is through standard web re-direct.
Product works well on desktop browser. Its not that bad on browsers on tablets. Not so great on phone browsers. The problem on mobile device is for obvious reasons, as the pages are optimized.

The standard approach we can do is go about optimizing for mobile browsers, and be happy. My team is flying with optimizing for mobile web, because they think apps will be very difficult to do.

If we choose to go the native app model, is developing a library or package for each platform the only way? I am thinking, no in current world with so much technology advancement. I am not a fan of browser view on device, not the smooth experience.

Are there other options available? I was looking at HTML5 hybrid applications, but can't put a finger to be sure that will work for what I am looking for.

Comment: Develop to a framework like Appcelerator or Phonegap.  IMHO...

Comment: Thanks, I am digging more. Need to know, been unable to sleep properly for a while :-)

Answer (score 0):

Frameworks aside, often times you can [use a stylesheet](http://www.seabreezecomputers.com/tips/mobile-css.htm) meant for mobile devices and hide everything that is not absolutely vital. You could also consider [WML](http://www.stemkoski.com/how-to-design-websites-for-mobile-phones/), but I think you could live without it IMAO.

Writing apps for the iOS will require an investment in Apple developer tools and training in Objective-C. Android will call for Java and Eclipse, to name a few things.

When it comes to "native apps", you will need to code for whatever platform you are depending on. The number of platforms you work with is entirely up to you, but yes, each new platform may require a different implementation.

Personally, I would add some specialized markup/styles to make as many *browsers* as possible happy. If you want to expand, try to see where your target audience really lies and reach out to them on any medium you can afford to build on. I would zone in on specialized applications if there are benefits really worth chasing down that road.

Comment: Thanks Sage for the update. We are looking for in APP experience, and wanting to stay out trying to stick to browsers. The option is to develop for each platform separately, but I was hoping there can be one solution that will cover multiple platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Hybrid applications is a good option, but probably the devil in a box.

The hybrid approach with HTML5 fits your developer, because they will still use HTML, CSS and JS (e.g. with PhoneGap), but on the other hand you will get an medium satisfying UI (what you said you are not a fan of).

Pure native applications is probably a bit too much of all good, if your web app runs fine in a browser.

A way could be to go with compiled hybrid and cross-platform compatible solutions like xamarin or appcelerator, especially appcelerator uses JS, which is an advantage for you. This could result in a native UI (implemented in JS) and shared business logic code. So there are two benefits for you; first, just use JS, second, shared business logic code -> less work.

Other alternative would be to go with responsive or adaptive websites, realized with the help of CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for developing a hybrid app (phonegap + angularJS + backend), I would like to recommend [Monaca](http://monaca.mobi/en/). I've just recently discover it. It is very cool since it has phonegap inside its framework and its own backend. Moreover, it also has a fast and lightweight UI framework called [OnsenUI](http://onsenui.io/) which is based on Topcoat and AngularJS.

Even it is a hybrid app but it will give users the native application feel since it also provides native components to use in your hybrid apps. What is impressive about it, you don't even need to build and install your app to your device every time during development. That's what I love the most about this.

I hope it helps since I think it is just like what you are asking for. I'm just a novice developer and I find it is very easy to use.